# Changing audio url in wavesurfer.js load result in memory leak in AngularJS Application

Tags: javascript, audio, memory-leaks

I'm using [wavesurfer.js](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js) in a playlist project which will need to change the audio url frequently, but every time when I change the URL seems that the old audio buffer isn't cleared and result in memory leak appears in the chrome task manager. and the tab crashes after a while. How can I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug of the script, you can't do much about it.

#### Try these things:

1. Try cleaning your cache
2. Ask the developer

Comment: @phikry Did cleaning your cache work? Please upvote my answer if it worked!

Comment: @Matrijn I'll try it and if one of your options worked of course you deserve to be upvoted!

Comment: Thanks, i need rep so i can comment on questions :-)